# non-singular Riemann surface implies irreducible polynomial without connectedness?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry

Let
$$ F(w,z) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(z)w^{n-i}$$
be a polynomial in $z,w$. Define a Riemann surface as the set
$$\Gamma:= \left\{ (z,w)\in \mathbb C^2 \mid F(z,w)=0 \right\} $$
and call it non-singular if
$$\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial z},\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}\right)(z_0,w_0) \neq 0$$
for every point $(z_0,w_0) \in \Gamma$.

Question: I don't see how the non-singularity condition implies irreducibility of $F$, i.e. does $\Gamma$ connected follow from any of the above assumptions?

Comment: Let $F(z,w) = w^2-1$. Does it satisfy the conditions?

Comment: Non-singularity implies irreducibility for projective curves. If the polynomial factors, then the respective zero loci of the factors intersect by Bezout, and singularities happen there. But the points of intersection may all lie on the line at infinity. This is what happens with @Daniel's example (and Jo's answer). So if you compactify your Riemann surfaces in $\Bbb{P}^2(\Bbb{C})$, then the claim becomes true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-singularity does not imply irreducibility: Take $$F(z,w) := (z-z_0)(z-z_1), z_0 \neq z_1.$$ The zero set are two disjoint copies of $\mathbb C$.